# How to findIndex multidimensional array for predicate in Lodash?

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to search an array of arrays of objects like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            Id: 1
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            parentId: 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            Id: 3
        },
        {
            Id: 4,
            parentId: 3
        }
    ],
]
```

I want to search these nested objects for the predicate of Id or parentId and return the index of that array within the top level array. `_.findIndex` only seems to work for an array of objects.

If I was searching for index of Id = 2 for example, the index should return 0.

***How can I find the index of a nested object in a multidimensional array in Lodash?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the sub-array's index in a two dimensional array, use `Array.findIndex()` with `Array.some()` (or lodash equivalents). `Array.some()` will return `true` if the item is in the sub-array, and that will prompt `Array.findIndex()` to return the current sub-array's index:

```js
const arr = [[{"Id":1},{"Id":2,"parentId":1}],[{"Id":3},{"Id":4,"parentId":3}]]

const result = arr.findIndex(s => s.some(o => o.Id === 2))

console.log(result)
```

To handle multi-dimensional arrays of unknown depth, you can use a standard `for` loop. This recursive function returns an array of all nested indexed, or `null` if the item wasn't found:

```js
const findIndexRecursive = (predicate, arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i]

    if (predicate(item)) return [i] // if this is the needed item return it's index

    if (Array.isArray(item)) { // if the item is an array
      const idx = findIndexRecursive(predicate, item) // get the idx array from an item which is an array

      if (idx) return [i, ...idx] // if a not null result return the current and idx indexes
    }
  }

  return null
}

const arr = [[{"Id":1},{"Id":2,"parentId":1}],[{"Id":3},{"Id":4,"parentId":3}]]

const result = findIndexRecursive(o => o.Id === 2, arr)

console.log(result)
```